# IIS ARR redirect error 502.3

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, iis, https, arr

I'm trying to route HTTPS requests for domainname.com to an Apache backend webserver using ARR. The client is able to connect to ARR server just fine over HTTPS; the problem is when the ARR tries to fetch the site data from the apache webserver, it returns an error 502.3 (attached to this post).[image]

The same ARR, has been previously configured to route traffic to websites over using HTTPS, however this is the first one being routed to an apache server. Please do feel free to request additional information in efforts to help with this.

Help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Following further research, it was determined that in this case the 502.3 error is because the ARR server is unable to process the response of the backend apache server. The rules relevant to this website on the ARR are:

1. Rewrite http://domainname.com to https://www.domainname.com
2. Add exclusion for https://www.domainname.com for a rule which converts https to http.
3. Route traffic for https://www.domainname.com to server farm A

We've tested further using a test.html file; https://www.domainname.com/test/html. This also returned the same 502.3 error.

Comment: I don't know if I will be able to answer this question but posting the web.config that contains the ARR configuration will be needed.

Comment: @AranMulholland thanks for your response. Following further research, it seems that in this case, the ARR server is unable to process the response from the backend apache server, hence the 502.3 error. The web.config is definately ok, because other sites are setup in the same way; the only difference is that all the other https sites going through the ARR are hosted on an IIS backed server, where in this case the backend server is apache. Also added further information in the post itself under Update.